# Opening balance from Exact Online not coming through for I_EOL_BAL_PDER with Invantive Control

Tags: invantive-control, exact-online

When I use the formula `I_EOL_BAL_PDER`, the opening balance is not include in the amount.

How can I include the opening balance as well in the Excel formula?

Answer (score 0):

To also get the opening balance, you have to add it up using `I_EOL_BAL_YEAR_OPEN`.

For example:

```
=i_eol_bal_year_open($C{E,.,.,^+2,.} , $C{E,.,.,^,.}, $C{E,.,.,^+5,.}) + i_eol_bal_pder($C{E,.,.,^+2,.},$C{E,.,.,^,.},1,$C{E,.,.,^+1,.},$C{E,.,.,^+5,.})'
```

Comment: What is $C{...}? I think you can use A1 etc too.

Answer (score 0):

The cumulative is now also available as:

```
=i_eol_year_close(...)
```

which sums the opening balance plus all previous and the current period.